# POST costum stories in PHP FACEBOOK 5.0.0

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a little problem, I'm making an App who an user can find some treasure, and when he find it, the app will post a story like:

"user_name" "find" a "treasure" on MYAPP.

with the title ect...

now, I made this script:

```
$storyDinamic = ['object' => json_encode([
'fb:app_id' => '760699587345565',
'og:url' => 'http://samples.ogp.me/906181492797373',
'og:title' => 'gold',
'og:type' => 'eatsquare:treasure',
'og:image' => 'https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png',
'og:description' => 'I find a gold!!'
])
];

$request = $fb->post('/me/objects/eatsquare:treasure', $storyDinamic);  
$response = $request->getGraphUser();   
echo $response['id'];
```

now, this script works, and the page echo the id of the story? without any error, but when I go to the game feed, I can't see anything from my app.

If I try to post the story from the link like:

```
$storyStatic = ['treasure' => '"http://samples.ogp.me/906181492797373"'];
$request = $fb->post('/me/eatsquare:find', $storyStatic);
```

this works, but I need to change the variable og:title,og:image,og:description.

Someone know why I have this problem?

Thank you very much